# Using fastai to predict a single image

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, fast-ai

New to fastai, I'm just trying to get my model to predict a singular image using learner.predict function, but it gives the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'apply_tfms'. Is there something I'm formatting incorrectly?

```
learn = cnn_learner(data, base_arch=models.resnet18, metrics=accuracy, model_dir="/tmp/models", callback_fns=ShowGraph)
learn.fit_one_cycle(cyc_len=5)
interp = ClassificationInterpretation.from_learner(learn)

learn.predict('test/0.jpg')
```

Comment: can the predict function not take a string, or a PosixPath object?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read the image first instead of just passing it to the predict method.

You can use [`PIL`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) to open and read the image.

```py
# Read and open time image file
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('test/0.jpg')

# Get the predicted output
preds, _ = learn.predict(img)
```